# Keep SharePoint Environment Update

Tags: upgrade, update

I'm responsible for keeping our SharePoint 2010&2013 update and install all required update patches, How can I realize which update patches are required? should I install all PUs on our environment?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Their is no hard and fast rule for it. You have to make a decision. Typically, its depend upon the customer's requirement. If any given CU fix the problem you have in your farm then that should be apply. Once the Service Pack released then normally every body apply that because its become new base point for the Patches( future patch required that SP).

My rule is, my environment should have patch at least from 1 year or if their is compulsory hotfix for us.

[Common Question: What is the difference between a PU, a CU and a COD?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2013/03/21/common-question-what-is-the-difference-between-a-pu-a-cu-and-a-cod/)

Now check what version level of your farm and from their you can make the decision.

Comment: we are now in June 2015 CU, should I install any recent PU?

Comment: you are pretty much up to date, i dont think you need it unless their is any fix in the cu /pu after June. latest one is September 2015 CU,i think this is last for the SP 2010. But for 2013 we will have more.